# Send the error stack to a method

Tags: java

I have this error stack which I want to send to a method:

```
try {
// Some action
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    writeInfoMessage(e.printStackTrace());
}

public void writeInfoMessage(Exception message)
{
    log.info(message);
}
```

Can you tell me what is the proper way to send a error stack to a method?

Comment: Check out `e.getStackTrace()`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Throwable.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29)

> Provides programmatic access to the stack trace information printed by printStackTrace().

Comment: `::` means nothing in the context of java, so you might want to put it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your code will work because e.printStackTrace() returns **void** and your writeInfoMessage **expects a "Exception"** object. So either pass Exception object "e" and do log.info(e.printStackTrace()) or call e.getStackTrace() to get a Array of StackTraceElement objects for stack of error details